# Wiener process density

Tags: brownian-motion, density-function

Let $(W_{t},V_{t})$ be two independent Wiener processes.
We define $\tau_{a} = \inf\{t>0 : |W_{t}|=a\}$.
Find density of random variable $V_{\tau_{a}}$ for any $a>0$.
How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at these related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2883423/36150) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3082069/36150). There are some further similar questions on MSE ... just try to use the search